# How to really simulate an Iphone in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, devtools

I'm trying to post a story in Instagram using desktop Chrome (https://www.instagram.com).

The site allows you to post stories using the web version in an Iphone, but not in the desktop browser.

So to achieve this below is what i tried. But still, when i try to post a story, Instagram says 'Rotate your device to add to your story.'. Some setting is missing ; What else could i try to achieve this task ?

1 - Changed the user agent in network conditions to an Iphone user agent, so it can open the mobile version of Instagram instead of the desktop ; this worked and the mobile version is shown on desktop Chrome.

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_4 like Mac OS X)
> AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/87.0.4280.77
> Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1

2 - On sensors, change orientation to Portrait :
[image]

Comment: do you think it would help to set it to "portrait-primary" specifically? it seems to have something to do with your orientation by what they said (also I admire the grift lol)

Comment: @RaphaelMorgan what can i say, rules are made to be broken :-p . I don't see this 'portrait-primary' option on Sensors tab